# update phonegap app on the fly

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

I'm developing a phonegap app for Android and iOS and I want to be able to apply fixes and changes without having to resubmit the app to the app store. What is the recommended way to do this? 
I've seen several different ways to do it but none of them seem very efficient.

I've seen loading the content with jquery kind of like this...

HTML

```
<div ID="myContent"></div>
```

JS

```
$(#myContent).load("http://myurl.com/content.html")
```

Or having all your phonegap pages link to external webpages. (I'm not sure the app store will allow this)

I know iOS as of about a year ago will allow you to do this as long as you don't change the main functionality of the app.

My question is... What is a good way to be able to update HTML, js and CSS on the fly?

Comment: there are a few "hot code push" plugins